# golang how to use tool find where the ticker leak?

Tags: go, profile, ticker

I find my process use high cpu when there was not business request

I use `go-torch` find most of the cpu was waste in `runtime.timeproc`

I think it must because `time.NewTicker` leak(not stop) in somewhere, or create ticker in a for loop

so how can i using any tool to find it

in fact, i had search it and ever ticker was follow a `defer ticker.Stop()`

Comment: Can you please add a minimal and complete example following https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ? Your question is really hard to answer otherwise

Comment: I doubt ticker (or the time pkg) is causing _CPU_ load. Tickers can leak memory however, if you don't stop (to reclaim the channel they rely on). See the example [here](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTicker).

Answer (score 1):

I find the method to find out the leak Ticker

In heap profile, you can type:

`go tool pprof http://xxx/debug/pprof/heap`

```
tree time.NewTicker
```

can it will show where the ticker create, something like the following:

[image]